# Check if a value already exists on a <li> tag with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to know with jQuery if a certain value is on a `<li>` tag on an `<ul>`with a certain tag:

```
<ul id="timeline">
<li>MyValue</li>
<li>MySecondValue</li>
</ul>
```

How can I check with jQuery if for example, `MySecondvalue`, is already on the the `<ul>`with the `timeline` id? Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
if ( $('ul li:contains("MySecondValue")').length ) {
    //exists
}
```

Comment: Chances are you're wanting to check for user input, and with this solution you would unfortunately have to escape or sanitize the input somehow.

Answer (score 7):

```
$("ul li").filter(function() {
    return $(this).text() == "MySecondValue";
}).length;
```

If that expression returns 0, it is not on the list. Otherwise, it is.

Answer (score 1):

do something like this:

```
$('ul li').each(function(){ 
     if($(this).text()=='MySecondvalue') alert('already exists');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not quite jQuery-ish, but depending on the number of elements to filter, this could be the most performant way:

```
function alreadyInTimeline(text) {
    return ($('#timeline').html().match(new RegExp('\>(' + text + ')\<')) !== null);
}

alert(alreadyInTimeline('MyValue'));
```

cf. [the performance comparison of the answers given here so far on for a rather small timeline](http://jsperf.com/checking-existence-of-text-jquery-vs-match)

**Edit:** Disregard this, I just updated the jsperf test to use the same selectors for all cases and it turns out that I was wrong.